# The status remained "awaiting for reviewer selection" after 5 months since re-submission

Tags: publications

Anyone give me some advice:
I have made a major revision after receiving one very positive feedback and one very negative feedback for my manuscript. Then I revised and resubmitted. It is almost 5 months since resubmission. The status is remained “Awaiting Reviewer Selection” since then. I have emailed the editor several times, but I still have not received the feedback.
Have anyone had this experience and please give me an advice.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Contact someone else from the journal. This could be the editor-in-chief, the associate/managing editor if the journal has one, or simply the journal office. The journal is the only one who's able to solve your problem.

If the journal never replies regardless of who you contact, then you'll have to assume the journal is dead, withdraw your manuscript, and submit elsewhere.

Comment: Dear Allure, thank you very much for your sharing!

Comment: Yes, I have contacted the Editor in Chief several times. However, they have not responded! I don't know what happened!